# MySQL++ SSL Support on Linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, debian, mysql++

I am attempting to get MySQL++ to work correctly on Debian 6 with SSL support. I have tested everything on Windows 7 and it works great. Everything is encrypted. I am having a little bit of trouble porting it to Debian though.

This is my error:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mysqlpp::BadOption'
  what():  Option not supported by database driver v5.1.49`

This is my call for setting the certificate files:

`connection->set_option(new mysqlpp::SslOption("/root/certs/client-key.pem", "/root/certs/client-cert.pem", "/root/certs/ca-cert.pem", "/root/certs", "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA"));`

I have noticed that when configuring MySQL++ it looks for mysql_ssl_set() in libmysqlclient. It does not find that function.

`checking for mysql_ssl_set in -l... no`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed in MySQL++ 3.2.0, released today.

In older versions, there's a bug in the test for `mysql_ssl_set()`. If you cannot use the current version but can patch your version's source code, this will fix it:

```
Index: config/mysql_ssl.m4
===================================================================
--- config/mysql_ssl.m4 (revision 2696)
+++ config/mysql_ssl.m4 (working copy)
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
     #
     # Check for mysql_ssl_set() in libmysqlclient(_r)
     #
-    AC_CHECK_LIB($MYSQL_C_LIB, mysql_ssl_set, [
+    AC_CHECK_LIB($MYSQL_C_LIB_NAME, mysql_ssl_set, [
        AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET,, Define if your MySQL library has SSL functions)
     ]) dnl AC_CHECK_LIB(mysqlclient, mysql_ssl_set)
 ]) dnl  MYSQL_WITH_SSL
```

You will then need to re-bootstrap the source tree, and rebuild.